# why can't I resize my views anymore?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I'm using Xcode 4.6.2, and am having trouble resizing my views.

For instance, I just created a new Storyboard, and dropped one regular UIView on top of another. I went to to change it's top, by grabbing the handle, and the whole top line became red, and would not move.

Now, I can force it to move by holding down the option key (or is it the command key), but I used to be able to resize views pretty easily it Xcode. I'm wondering, is Auto Layout causing me these headaches? Or is it some setting that I'm missing? I just want to resize my newly-dropped view, by dragging the handles, but can't.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot when you try to resize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think it is autolayout.  In building my views when I have seen the behavior you describe it is because I'm resizing a view that has fairly rigid constraints between its edges and other views.  I usually get around it by first updating my constraints to something less restrictive (by deleting or lowering the priority) and then reviewing the constraints once I have resized it.

You may also have success unchecking the options in the `When Resizing Views Apply Constraints To...` menu.  In the storyboard editor it is in buttons on the lower right and looks like two rectangles (windows) with one smaller than the other.

Comment: I unchecked the "When Resizing Views" options, and now all is well. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned solution didn't work for me.

What i did to resolve this issue was that i explicitly set the frame of the view in `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 280.0, 170.0);  // explicitly set your view's frame
}
```